# How to select the correct name for the main title from the list?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data frame and would like to histogram each column of this data frame using `hist` function. Also, suppose that, for each column, I would like to get different main title. Where the
 main title can be obtained from a list.

Here is my code:

```
> xxxy
        V1       V2       V3       V4       V5       V6       V7       V8       V9      V10
1 2.467732 3.453399 2.995019 2.921341 2.913492 3.982306 3.105757 3.485926 2.521138 1.810061
2 2.588249 3.502873 2.989261 2.911928 3.118633 3.905069 2.939321 3.530552 2.505202 1.794859

> as.data.frame(xxxy)
        V1       V2       V3       V4       V5       V6       V7       V8       V9      V10
1 2.467732 3.453399 2.995019 2.921341 2.913492 3.982306 3.105757 3.485926 2.521138 1.810061
2 2.588249 3.502873 2.989261 2.911928 3.118633 3.905069 2.939321 3.530552 2.505202 1.794859


#the name of the main title for each histogram plot.
    nam <- list("Var1","Var2","Var3","Var4","Var5","Var6","Var7","Var8","Var9","Var10")
```

Then I would like to histogram each variables using `hist`. Where, I would like to get different main title for each one using `apply` function as follows:

```
> hist(xxxy[[1]],main = paste("Histogram of", nam[[1]])
```

It worked based on the comment of @RuiBarradas. however, I would like to do it over a list. Then I use this code:

```
> apply(xxxy,2,function(x)hist(x,main=lapply(1:10,function(i)paste("Hist of " ,nam[[i]]))))
```

It worked but all the main title is "Hist of var1" that means 
`main=lapply(1:10,function(i)paste("Hist of " ,nam[[i]]))`

does not work over the list of the names.

How I can do this with `apply` function. How can I make the title changed automatically. Any help please?

Comment: Start with `nam <- names(xxxy)` and then use `paste("Histogram of" nam[[1]])`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thank you so much for your help. I tried it but get an error.                                                                                                           `> nam <- names(xxxy)`
`> hist(xxxy[[1]],main = paste("Histogram of" nam[[1]]))`
`Error: unexpected symbol in "hist(xxxy[[1]],main = paste("Histogram of" nam"`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot, there's a comma between `"Histogram of"` and `nam[[1]]`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I see where is the mistake, I should put `,` .  `paste("Histogram of" , nam[[1]]`. But how can I do it for a list with `apply`?  Thanks for all your help.

Comment: You have not passed the list `nam` in the anonymous function(`lapply` part). Pass that as the second argument and try.

Comment: @tushaR Thank you so much for your help. I tried your suggestion (as I understand you) but it is the same. `apply(xxxy,2,function(x)hist(x,main=lapply(nam,function(x)paste("hist " ,x))))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'll give it a try.
First of all, instead of using your dataset, I'll make up one. The reason why is that you want to plot histograms, so I guess your real data has more than two rows (just two values per histogram).

```
xxxy <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(1e3), ncol = 10))
names(xxxy) <- paste0('V', 1:10)
```

Now the code to display them all. Note that I display them in the same graph. In order to do that, I use graphic parameter `mfrow`. Then after the plotting is done, reset the original graphics parameters.

```
nam <- names(xxxy)

op <- par(mfrow = c(2, 5))
lapply(seq_along(nam), function(i)
        hist(xxxy[[i]],main = paste("Histogram of", nam[[i]]))
)

par(op)
```

That's it. I've iterated over the length of `nam`, and did it with just one `lapply`, without the need for nested ones.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sapply(1:ncol(xxxy),
function(t,df,nam){hist(x = df[,t],main=paste("Hist of",nam[[t]]))},xxxy,nam)
```